# Can't convert xlsx to csv properly

Tags: excel, csv, xlsx

I've noticed that my xlsx file cannot be transformed into a csv file because of Excel's "Total number of characters that a cell can contain" https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3

I'd like to know if you have any tips to bypass this limitation, I need this file into a CSV format. I am considering downloading Numbers by Apple. Not Sure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You have more than 32,767 characters in a single cell?

Comment: Yes, I do. :) :)

Comment: One word question: why?

Comment: You'll find a way to abuse Numbers too then. FWIW the limit used to be 255 characters. The problem is the obviously unstructured data, not Excel.

Comment: It's a list of all stocks traded since 2004. There are plenty.

Comment: There is no reason for any cell to hold any more than a few dozen characters then, across maybe several hundreds of thousands of rows. Without showing what your data looks like, it's unlikely you're going to get any actionable feedback. The only sensible thing to do is to structure the data you have so that it's cleanly organized into proper columns. CSV export will then be seamless. Maybe PowerQuery can help clean up the data, who knows.

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.

Answer (score 0):

My own provisional answer is to split the over-used cell into multiple sub-cells. Better ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

From what your describing, you need a Word document, not an excel document with > 32k characters. 
Can you share sample data set to explain in more detail.